# Are O, B stars present in SDSS survey?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy

I am currently working on a problem of defining the distribution of massive stars, like O-B stars and I am looking for some information about them in SDSS data releases. In SEGUE program they are listing 15 different types of stars, but none of them are not what I am looking for. So there is a reliable question, is there any data about OB stars in SDSS? if there is not what catalogs should I use?

Comment: A comment discussion has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63540/discussion-on-question-by-ayan-nussupbekov-are-o-b-stars-present-in-sdss-survey).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the distribution of fields observed in SEGUE, plotted in Galactic coordinates.

[image: SEGUE survey]

The survey focused on high Galactic latitudes, to investigate the Galactic halo.

O/B stars are born in rich clusters, from gas and dust close to the Galactic plane. Since these massive stars they have short lives (a few to a few tens of millions of years), they do not get the chance to move far from their birthplaces, unless ejected from a binary system or cluster as a rare runaway star. Even then, they would not normally be found more than a couple of hundred pc from the Galactic plane.

The bright limit of SEGUE was about magnitude 14. The least luminous B star has an *absolute* magnitude of 0. Therefore even the least luminous B star
would have to be about 6000 pc away to be included in SEGUE. Even at Galactic latitudes as low as 20 degrees (about the SEGUE limit), this places the star at 2000 pc from the Galactic plane.

Therefore O/B stars should be *extremely* rare (and interesting) in SEGUE.

Edit: There are catalogues of O/B stars that might suit your purposes (none will be spatially complete for the entire Galaxy because of dust obscuration in the plane). e.g. [The Catalog of Galactic OB stars by Reed (2003)](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/374771) or the [Galactic O star catalogue by Maiz Apellaniz (2004)](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0311196).

Comment: Thanks, your answer is good, but the problem remains unsolved... By any chance, do you know good bright stars catalog? I know that there is Hipparcos, which I am using now, but maybe there is something else.

Comment: @AyanNussupbekov see edit